# iOS - global variable to measure launch time

Tags: ios, program-entry-point, appdelegate

Somewhere in the main function of my app I need to set a global variable to the current `CFAbsoluteTime`, so that I can compare it to the current time in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` so that I can measure the launch time. My question is where in the following code would I insert this code, and where would I put the global variable?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: global variable -> at "global" (=file) scope. The location of the initial call to the timer is (should be) obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not so much an answer as a suggestion...have you tried just putting a line in right above the return? something along the lines of

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {


        timevariable = [CFAbsoluteTime currentTime];
        //or whatever the function call is

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

or even possibly just using NSLog and then manually subtracting on your own

Comment: This only answers half of the question. Where should the global variable be defined?

Comment: Right, but where do I put "timevariable" so that I can access it from other files (such as AppDelegate).

Comment: The app actually needs to do something with the launch time so NSLog doesn't help in this case.

Comment: ok so try doing `extern <variabletype> <variablename>` right above the `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: ok, extern CFAbsoluteTime launchTime; ... but in AppDelegate.m, how would I access it? AppDelegate doesn't seem to know about it.

Comment: ok I *think* at that point you have to import "main.m" into your app delegate

Comment: @Ben No - you do not import a .m file.

Comment: ok scratch all of that.  Create a .h file "global.h" and put `extern type variable` in there.  Then import that .h file into your main.m and your app delegate

Comment: Actually if you put 'extern' in AppDelegate, you can read the variable from main.m. The last comment you made would probably work too. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for measuring launch time. Even on a slow device (3GS) than obviously takes 4-5 seconds to load, the CFAbsoluteTime difference between main() and applicationDidFinishLaunching is .3 seconds. Also if you NSLog something in main(), it doesn't log to the console until the app finishes launching.

Comment: well iOS usually loads all of the app resources into memory and then will begin to actually launch the app.  So there will be a period of time after you click the icon but before main.m is being executed and there is no way to access that unless you could edit what the operating system is doing.